# how can I write into or select form a already existing table in a encrypted database (via SQLCipher, Android SQLite)?

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher-android

I try to write into a existing table in a encrypted(SQLCipher) database, but i get the error message "net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such table ". How can i do it?

I have created a SQLCipher database and table via SQLite studio  in the assets folder in my project. 
then i try to write into the table.

every time that the app starts would be the table created renew??

the methods in DatabaseHelper class:

```
 import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.util.Log;

    import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

    import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;

    import java.io.File;

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbName) {
            super(context, dbName, null, 1);
        }
    //Command Out
       /* public void InitializeSQLCipher(File databaseFile, String dbPass, String tableName) {

            databaseFile.mkdirs();
            databaseFile.delete();
            SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dbPass, null);
            database.execSQL("create table " + tableName + "( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  columnOne  TEXT, columnTwo TEXT)");

            database.close();
        }*/

        public void FillSQLCipher(File databaseFile, String dbPass, String tableName, String columnOne, String columnTwo, String values) {

            SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dbPass, null);

            ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();

            cValues.put(columnOne, values);
            cValues.put(columnTwo, values);

            database.insert(tableName, null, cValues);

            database.close();
        }

        public void getDataFromTable(File databaseFile, String dbPass, String tableName) {

            try {

                SQLiteDatabase enDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dbPass, null);

                Cursor cursor = enDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + tableName, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                            String neu = cursor.getString(i);
                            Log.d("Data: ", neu + "");
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                    enDatabase.close();
                }
                cursor.close();
                enDatabase.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(tableName, "can not read the table!");
            }
        }

        public void cleanData(File databaseFile, String dbPass, String tableName) {

            SQLiteDatabase database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(databaseFile, dbPass, null);
            database.execSQL("delete from " +tableName);
            database.close();

        }


    }
```

//and i the Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);

        Date now = new Date();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        //time now
        Log.d("** Zeit jetzt: ", String.valueOf(now));
        Log.d("** Milisekunden: ", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

        ***************************************\n");

        Log.d("** verschlüsselte", "Datenbank:\n");


        //Fill the table in the encrypted database
        DatabaseHelper enDBHelper = new EncryptedDatabaseHelper(this, "encryptedDB.db");
        File databaseFile = getDatabasePath("encryptedDB.db");
        enDBHelper.InitializeSQLCipher(databaseFile, "abc123", "encryptedTableOne");

        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
            int randomValue = new Random().nextInt();
            enDBHelper.FillSQLCipher(databaseFile, "abc123", "encryptedTableOne", "ColumnOne", "ColumnTwo", String.valueOf(randomValue));
        }

        //time now
        now = new Date();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("** Zeit jetzt: ", String.valueOf(now));
        Log.d("** Milisekunden: ", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));


        Log.d("\n", " daten aus der verschlüsselten Datenbank  ***************************************\n");

        //read the table from encrypted database!
        enDBHelper.getDataFromTable(databaseFile, "abc123", "encryptedTableOne");
       /* enDBHelper.cleanData(databaseFile, "abc123", "encryptedTableOne");*/

        Log.d("\n*******************", "\n");

        now = new Date();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("** Zeit jetzt: ", String.valueOf(now));
        Log.d("** Milisekunden: ", String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

        Log.d("\n", " und hier ist Ende ***************************************\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question requires more information.  Like code.

Comment: Share what you tried so far so people can help you

Comment: I have created a SQLCipher database and table via SQLite studio  in the assets folder in my project. 
then i try to write into the table.